# Thread-Safe lazy initialization in getter

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, getter

I would like to know if both of the following solutions for lazy initialization are correct.

I have a class `AppContext` that is supposed to hold references to other class that should only exist once (Avoiding making every single one of these classes a singleton). Let's say one of these other classes is called `ReferencedClass`. That being said, I would like to lazy-initialize the references with defaults, in a thread-safe way.

It has been discussed before, and I have read a lot about it, but I am still unsure. Personal preferences aside, what I would like know is: **Are these two solutions a correct way to implemented my desired behavior?**

---

**Solution 1:** Originally I wanted to implement it like this:

```
// Getter with lazy initialized default value
- (ReferencedClass *)referencedClass {
    // Check if nil. If yes, wait for lock and check again after locking.
    if (_referencedClass == nil) { 
        @synchronized(self) {
            if (_referencedClass == nil) { 
                // Prevent _referencedClass pointing to partially initialized objects
                ReferencedClass *temp = [[ReferencedClass alloc] init]; 
                _referencedClass = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return _referencedClass;
}

// Setter
- (void)setReferencedClass:(ReferencedClass *)referencedClass {
    @synchronized(self) {
        _referencedClass = referencedClass;
    }
}
```

---

**Solution 2:** Then I decided to go with GCD instead, so I wrote this:

```
// Getter with lazy initialized default value
- (ReferencedClass *)referencedClass {
    // Check if nil. If yes, wait for "lock" and check again after "locking".
    if (_referencedClass == nil) { 
        dispatch_sync(syncDispatchQueue, ^{
            if (_referencedClass == nil) {
                // Prevent _referencedClass pointing to partially initialized objects
                ReferencedClass *temp = [[ReferencedClass alloc] init]; 
                _referencedClass = temp;
            }
        });
    }
    return _referencedClass;
}

// Setter
- (void)setReferencedClass:(ReferencedClass *)referencedClass {
    dispatch_sync(syncDispatchQueue, ^{
        _referencedClass = referencedClass;
    });
}
```

Of course, somewhere (for example in the `init`-Method) I have initialized the `syncDispatchQueue` with something like:

```
syncDispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.stackoverflow.lazy", NULL);
```

---

Is this correct, thread-safe and deadlock-free code? Can I use the double-checked-locking together with the `temp`-variable? If this double-checked-locking is not safe, would my code in both cases be safe if I removed the outer checks? I guess so, right?

Thanks very much in advance!

[**Side note:** *I am aware of dispatch_once and that some people say that (in contrary to the Apple documentation) it can also be used with instance variables. For now I would like to use one of these two options though. If possible.* ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand it, your "double-checked locking" mechanism is *not* thread-safe,
because the assigment `_referencedClass = ...` is not atomic. So one thread might read a partially initialized variable in the outer `if (_referencedClass == nil)` check.

If you remove the outer checks, both versions look OK to me.

You may be interested in

- [What advantage(s) does dispatch_sync have over @synchronized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599401/what-advantages-does-dispatch-sync-have-over-synchronized)

which has a great answer explaining the differences in implementation and performance.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the quick answer. I have updated the code above in order to avoid the problem you mentioned. Would that be working now? Otherwise I guess I skip the outer checks, wound't hurt anyway. Thanks for pointing out the link, it is interesting indeed.

Comment: @LKK: `_referencedClass = temp;` does not fix the problem, because this assignment is also not atomic. You have to remove the outer check.