# iOS Objective C Override Property Setter

Tags: android, ios, objective-c

In a class I have `@property BOOL clearCookies;`

I'd like to set it up so that I can do some additional things when the item is set.

In my code I could do something like `classInstance.clearCookies = YES;`

Then in the setter method something like this java example from android:

```
public void setClearCookies(boolean clearCookies) {
        _instance.clearCookies = clearCookies;
        _instance.doOtherThings();
    }
```

What's the best way to achieve that in Objective C? Basically I want to set the boolean property but then also do some other things (actually clearing the cookies from my `UIWebView`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(void)setClearCookies:(BOOL)clearCookies
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
       _clearCookies = clearCookies;
       [self doOtherThings];
   } 
}

- (BOOL)clearCookies
{
   @synchronized (self)
   {
       return _clearCookies;
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks perfect! Thanks for the speedy response!

Comment: Looks like it doesn't like have a synthesized getter: `writable atomic property cannot pair a synthesized getter with a user defined setter`. Would you mind providing an example of how to write a getter for this as well? :)

Comment: It would be better to make the property nonatomic rather than leave it as atomic but implement the getter/setter in nonatomic ways.

Comment: @TomHammond I updated my answer. This code will keep the setter and the getter atomic

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
-(void)setClearCookies:(BOOL)clearCookies {
        _clearCookies = clearCookies;
       [self doOtherThings];
    }
```

Comment: Isn't that java though? :)

Comment: @TomHammond haha updated syntax - java/swift confusion - finally corrected :D

Answer (score 1):

Another way to avoid thread conflicts (alternative to `@synchronized()`), is using Grand Central Dispatch (which in the majority of cases is [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599401/what-advantages-does-dispatch-sync-have-over-synchronized) than the former):

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL clearCookies;

// Later in code
static dispatch_queue_t clearCookiesQueue;

- (void)setClearCookies:(BOOL)clearCookies {
    [self initializeClearCookiesQueue];

    dispatch_async(clearCookiesQueue, ^{ // Note, this is "async"
        _clearCookies = clearCookies;
    });
}


- (BOOL)clearCookies {
    [self initializeClearCookiesQueue];

    __block BOOL clearCookies;
    dispatch_sync(clearCookiesQueue, ^{ // Note, this is "sync"
        clearCookies = _clearCookies;
    });

    // As "sync" waits until the operation is finished, you can define
    // your other operations here safely.
    [self doOtherStuff];

    return clearCookies;
}


/**
    Checks if the queue for the clearCookies property is initialized and,
    if it's not, initializes it.
*/
- (void)initializeClearCookiesQueue {
    if ( ! clearCookiesQueue ) {
        // We'll use a serial queue to avoid conflicts reading/writing the ivar
        clearCookiesQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.yourapp.yourviewcontroller.someUniqueIdentifier", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL); // Note, this is a C string, not NSString
    }
}
```

If you don't care about threading, or you don't need it, just overriding your setter is enough:

```
- (void)setClearCookies:(BOOL)clearCookies {
    _clearCookies = clearCookies;
    [self doOtherStuff];
}
```